# Get the cell value of the third column on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a button in the first column of my datagrid, and when I click it I'm trying to get the cell value of 3rd column of that row I clicked the button on. So for example I click the button on row 3 of my datagrid I want the cell value of column 3, row 3 which is an int. How can I do that?

XAML for the button:

```
<Control:DataGrid.Columns>              
    <Control:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <Control:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                 <Button Click="ShowHideDetailsClick" Foreground="Black">+</Button>
              </DataTemplate>
        </Control:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </Control:DataGridTemplateColumn>
<Control:DataGrid.Columns>
```

C# to handle click:

```
private void ShowHideDetailsClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //want to get cell value here
   System.Windows.Controls.Button expandCollapseButton = (System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender;
   DependencyObject obj = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
   while (!(obj is ExtendedGrid.Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow) && obj != null) obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
        if (obj is ExtendedGrid.Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow)
        {
            if (null != expandCollapseButton && "+" == expandCollapseButton.Content.ToString())
            {
                (obj as ExtendedGrid.Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow).DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                expandCollapseButton.Content = "-";
            }
            else
            {
                (obj as ExtendedGrid.Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow).DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                expandCollapseButton.Content = "+";
            }
        }
 }
```

I use a DataTable to fill my datagrid with data retrieved from a database, see code below:

```
public DataTable SourceTable
{
        get
        {
            return _sourceTable;
        }
        set
        {
            _sourceTable = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SourceTable");

        }
 }

SourceTable = new DataTable();

SourceTable.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]{
                new DataColumn("InputID", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("TraderID", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("TradeDate", typeof(DateTime)),
                new DataColumn("TradeTime", typeof(TimeSpan)),
                new DataColumn("ClientName", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("CurPair", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Amnt", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("Action", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("ExecutedRate", typeof(decimal))
            });

DataRow rowSource = null;

var OpenTradesQuery = from qa in connection.QuickAnalyzerInputs
                                  where qa.TradeClosedDateTime == null
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      qa.InputID,
                                      qa.TraderID,
                                      qa.ClientTradedDate,
                                      qa.ClientTradedTime,
                                      qa.ClientName,
                                      qa.CurrencyPair,
                                      qa.TradedAmount,
                                      qa.Action,
                                      qa.ExecutedRate
                                  };

foreach (var rowObj in OpenTradesQuery)
                {
                    rowSource = SourceTable.NewRow();
                    SourceTable.Rows.Add(rowObj.InputID, rowObj.TraderID, rowObj.ClientTradedDate, rowObj.ClientTradedTime, rowObj.ClientName, rowObj.CurrencyPair, rowObj.TradedAmount, rowObj.Action, rowObj.ExecutedRate);
                }
```

And then in my XAML the datagrid is binding SourceTable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before anything, I'll suggest to create a little Class that will contains information about the Rows of the Database, that will populate the Datagrid. This will help you for some facilities in your code. Also that will help for implementing my answer.

The Class will be something like this:

```
   public class PopulateData
   {
        public int       InputID;
        public String    TraderID;
        public DateTime  TradeDate;
        public TimeSpan  TradeTime;
        public string    ClientName;
        public string    CurPair;
        public int       Amnt;
        public string    Action;
        public decimal   ExecutedRate;

        public PopulateData(int iId, string tId, DateTime date, TimeSpan tTime, string cName, string curPair, int amnt, string Act, decimal ExRate)
        {
          InputID   = iId; 
          TraderID  = tId;
          TradeDate = date;
          TradeTime  = tTime;
          ClientName = cName;
          CurPair    = curPair;
          Amnt       = amnt;
          Action     = Act;
          ExecutedRate = ExRate;
        }
   }
```

So when you populate the SourceTable, do something like this:

```
  foreach (var rowObj in OpenTradesQuery)
  {
     rowSource = SourceTable.NewRow();
     SourceTable.Rows.Add(new PopulateData( rowObj.InputID, rowObj.TraderID, rowObj.ClientTradedDate, rowObj.ClientTradedTime, rowObj.ClientName, rowObj.CurrencyPair, rowObj.TradedAmount, rowObj.Action, rowObj.ExecutedRate));
  }
```

After you get the row corresponding to your button (the DataGridRow) it's almost done:
You now have to get what is inside the row; a PopulateData actually.

```
    private void ShowHideDetailsClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

      System.Windows.Controls.Button expandCollapseButton =  (System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender;
      DependencyObject obj = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
     while (!(obj is ExtendedGrid.Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow) && obj != null) obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
     //Get your entire row view here
       if(obj != null && obj is ExtendedGrid.Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow)
       {
          DataGridRow d = obj as DataGridRow; //Convert into DataGridRow
          PopulateData st = d.Item as PopulateData; //Get the PopulateData

          if (st.TraderID == "what you wants") //Or something else in the Class
          {
            // some stuff here
          } 
       }




        if (obj is ExtendedGrid.Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow)
        {
           if (null != expandCollapseButton && "+" == expandCollapseButton.Content.ToString())
           {
             (obj as ExtendedGrid.Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow).DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
             expandCollapseButton.Content = "-";
           }
            else
            {
              (obj as ExtendedGrid.Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow).DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            expandCollapseButton.Content = "+";
            }
        }
     }
```

and that's it , let me know if it works for you.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm getting an error thou in the line item var row = (DataRowView)obj.Row.Item; it says that " 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' does not contain a definition for 'Row' and no extension method 'Row' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" @Lionnel Afangbedjee

Comment: Oh ok sorry for that, i've edit my code to avoid that. Tell me if it works this time :) @kknaguib

Comment: This line List<String> st = d.Item as List<String>; is giving me an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" @Lionnel Afangbedjee

Comment: What type of collection do you add to the Datagrid ? I mean, is that all int data ? can you edit your question with that ? I've set List<String> in my code for the example since I didn't know what kind of collection you are using

Comment: oh sorry yes I use a DataTable I'll update it one second @Lionnel Afangbedjee

Comment: Ok hope that this one will be the right one :) I've edit my answer try and let me know

Comment: Thanks! @Lionnel Afangbedjee